# Polymorphic string that describes each child class

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have a couple of chemical reactions. One of them is described as `"If insulin is mixed with antibiotic, healthy people catch Fever"`. I think it would be useful for logging to keep these description strings inside the code. I have thought of 2 approaches but they both seem kind of wrong.

#### Approach 1

```
public abstract class ChemicalReaction {

    public abstract String getDescription();
}

public class AntibioticInsulinReaction {

    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "If insulin is mixed with antibiotic, healthy people catch Fever";

    public String getDescription(){ return DESCRIPTION; }
}
```

Instance method returns a static variable.

#### Approach 2

```
public final class ChemicalReaction {

    private final String description;

    public ChemicalReaction(final String description){

        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription(){ return description; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ChemicalReaction antibioticInsulinReaction = new ChemicalReaction("If insulin is mixed with antibiotic, healthy people catch Fever");
    }
}
```

Magic string.

Do you see any other way to do it? Or maybe I don't need to?

Comment: Hard to advise you, without knowing what other functionality needs to be supported by these `ChemicalReaction` objects. I've voted to close the question for lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of `Enum`. As [oracle says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Consider following example:

```
enum ChemicalReaction {
    ANTIBIOTIC_INSULIN("If insulin is mixed with antibiotic, healthy people catch Fever");

    private String description;
    ChemicalReaction(String s) {
        this.description = s;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChemicalReaction reaction = ChemicalReaction.ANTIBIOTIC_INSULIN;

    if (reaction == ChemicalReaction.ANTIBIOTIC_INSULIN) {
        System.out.println("Safe == check");
    }

    switch (reaction) {
        case ANTIBIOTIC_INSULIN:
            System.out.println("Easy switch");
    }

    for (ChemicalReaction chemicalReaction : ChemicalReaction.values()) {
        System.out.println(chemicalReaction.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Enums support a lot of cool things, like comparing with `==`, simple use in `switch` statements, they can include methods and other fields in class body, have already several helper methods like static `.values()` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared.